# How to wait for the input from user and proceed with further code in erlang concurrent programming?

Tags: concurrency, erlang, erlang-shell

I am working with concurrent programming in Erlang where i am trying to exchange messages between two users. So i have hardcoded one set of messages which sent as message one by one from user1 to another user2, i am reading the input from keyboard and pass that input as reply to the user1. But while executing it the input is not taken and the message passing continues without input and asks for the input at last after completion of all processes.

```
-module(third).
-import(lists,[nth/2]).
-export([start/0,user2/5,user1/3,inp/1]).

inp(P) ->
{ok, [S]} = io:fread("entry: \n", "~s"),

P ! S.


user2(0, USERID1,_,_,_) ->
USERID1 ! bye,
io:format("finish");

user2(N, USERID1,Mess,Rep,K) ->
USERID1 ! {message, self(),Mess,K},
receive
    reply ->

    S=self(),
        spawn(third, inp, [S])
end,
user2(N-1, USERID1,Mess,Rep,K+1).

user1(Mess,Rep,K) ->
receive
        bye ->
            io:format("conversation over");
        {message, USERID2,Mess,K} ->
            io:format("~p~n",[nth(K,Mess)]),
            USERID2 ! reply,
            user1(Mess,Rep,K+1)
    end.

start() ->
Mess=["HEY","sup","how are you","yhank you","bye"],
USERID1=spawn(third, user1, [Mess,Rep,1]), 
spawn(third, user2, [5,USERID1,Mess,Rep,1]).
```

How do i wait for the input and then pass on that message.
When executed the start module the output is as follows -

```
1> c(third).
{ok,third} 
2> third:start().
"HEY"
<0.77.0>
entry: 
"sup"
entry: 
entry: 
"how are you"
entry: 
entry: 
"yhank you"
entry: 
entry: 
"bye"
entry: 
finishentry: 
entry: 
conversation overentry:
```

When it is prompting for entry , it should wait for the entry and then proceed.

Comment: Actually this code will not work. start() function refers to Rep variable that doesn't exists

Comment: You can write erlang code any way you want, but if you want help then you have to indent your code properly.  And, you have to give your variables and functions meaningful names.  Just so you know, erlang is not a beginner's language.  If you are new to programming, I suggest you try python instead.

Answer (score 1):

The version given later works as you expect - at least I think so, because there are not a lot of comment neither in your question, nor in your code.

it contains 2 modifications:

1. As said Odobenus, if you spawn the function inp, the function user2
   gets imediately the return value of spawn which is the pid of the
   spawned process, not the string entered by the user. Thus user2
   doesn't wait for anything else. The process still exists, so it will
   prompt "entry:", wait for an input, but it won't use it, and the
   string is lost as soon as entered.
2. There is another issue at the last line, when you spawn the function user2. Again, the start
   function stops immediately when it has got the pid of the new
   process; as it was started by a shell command, the shell takes the
   control of the io immediately, and the user2 process will never get
   the string entered by the user since it will be interpreted as a command by the shell.

'''

```
-module(third).

-export([start/0,user2/4,user1/2,inp/1]).

inp(P) ->
    S = io:get_line("entry: \n"),
    P ! S.


user2(0, USERID1,_,_) ->
    USERID1 ! bye,
    io:format("finish");

user2(N, USERID1,Mess,K) ->
    USERID1 ! {message, self(),Mess,K},
    io:format("user2 wait for reply~n"),
    receive
        reply ->
            S=self(),
            inp(S)
    end,
    user2(N-1, USERID1,Mess,K+1).

user1(Mess,K) ->
    receive
        bye ->
            io:format("conversation over");
        {message, USERID2,Mess,K} ->
            io:format("~p~n",[lists:nth(K,Mess)]),
            USERID2 ! reply,
            user1(Mess,K+1)
    end.

start() ->
    Mess=["HEY","sup","how are you","yhank you","bye"],
    USERID1=spawn(third, user1, [Mess,1]),
    user2(5,USERID1,Mess,1).
```

'''

However, in your example the two user processes do not really communicate: they do not examine the messages, and they exchange each time the complete collection of messages. I propose you to examine this other version, bye default, after 5 exchanges, user 1 close the chat, but user 2 can stop it before by entering the message "bye".

'''

```
-module(third).

-export([start/0,user2/1,user1/1]).


user2(USERID1) ->
    S = io:get_line("entry: \n"),
    USERID1 ! {message, self(),S},
    io:format("user2 wait for reply~n"),
    maybe_continue_user2(USERID1,S).

maybe_continue_user2(_,"bye\n") ->
    io:format("User2 ends the chat~n");
maybe_continue_user2(USERID1,_) ->
    receive
        {reply,"bye"} ->
            io:format("bye, close chat~n");
        {reply,Mess} ->
            io:format("user2 got ~p~n",[Mess]),
            user2(USERID1)
    end.

user1([]) ->
    io:format("User1 ends the chat~n");
user1([H|T]) ->
    receive
        {message,_,"bye\n"} ->
            io:format("user 1: conversation over~n");
        {message, USERID2,Mess} ->
            io:format("~p~n",[Mess]),
            USERID2 ! {reply,H},
            user1(T)
    end.

start() ->
    Mess=["HEY","sup","how are you","thank you","bye"],
    USERID1=spawn(third, user1, [Mess]),
    user2(USERID1).
```

'''

an example where user 2 stops the chat:

```
9> third:start().
entry:
hi
user2 wait for reply
"hi\n"
user2 got "HEY"
entry:
how are you?
user2 wait for reply
"how are you?\n"
user2 got "sup"
entry:
bye
user2 wait for reply
user 1: conversation over
User2 ends the chat
ok
10>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    register(user1, spawn(my, user1, [["Hello!", "How are you?", "Bye"]]) ),
    register(user2, spawn(my, user2, []) ),
    start_finished.

user1([]) ->
    {user1, terminated};
user1([String|Strings])->
    timer:sleep(500), %% See discussion below.
    user2 ! String,

    receive
        Reply -> io:format("user1 received: ~s~n", [Reply])
    end,

    user1(Strings).

user2() ->
    receive
        "Bye" -> io:format("Bye~n");
        Msg -> 
            Prompt = io_lib:format("~s~n>>> ", [Msg]),
            Reply = io:get_line(Prompt),
            user1 ! Reply,
            user2()
    end.
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:start().
start_finished
Hello!
>>> Hi there!
user1 received: Hi there!

How are you?
>>> Good, and you?
user1 received: Good, and you?

Bye
3>
```

I'm not sure why I need the `timer:sleep()` call, but it prevents some type of race condition that causes `io:get_line()` to malfunction.

Answer (score -1):

the code that reads from stdin. You launch it in the separated process

```
spawn(third, inp, [S])
```

every time when user2 process receives 'reply' atom

And btw result of user input will be send to user2 process and will never used.